# Get video resolution on Mac via .NET

Tags: .net, macos, mono, resolution, monomac

I can get informations about video-files like resolution by using the Shell32.dll under windows.

Is there some way to do this (in C# - running under the mono framework) that will work on Mac?

Comment: C# does not run on Mac - you have to use Objective-C there.

Comment: Erik: C# works perfectly under Mac OSX :-) and nothing prevents you from using a lot of other languages unrelated to Objective C.

Comment: wow - now I can't understand what are you asking - do you ask what is the resolution of the screen you are looking at, or a video file that you have on disk?

Comment: I never mentioned I need the resolution of the screen.
I want to get the resolution of a video file.

Comment: You didn't, but poupou did elaborate answer on obtaining resolution of the screen and was upvoted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is unclear to me, here are two part answer:

```
1. if you want to check the resolution of your screen (desktop):
```

Check if this is implemented: `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`.

For now, there is some code for it but it's marked with [MonoTODO] attribute.

`AllScreens`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx

Source for the library: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Screen.cs.htm

```
2. if you want to check video file resolution
```

For that, I would seek `ffmpeg` built for Mac and using command line parameters extract resolution information from the file.

http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html

Comment: I want to check video file resolution. I've already wrote an application which does that for Windows. Is there a way, with Mono, to convert that application, so that it would work on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Use [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) and look at [MonoMac.AppKit.NSScreen](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=N%3aMonoMac.AppKit). It should have all the properties you need to retrieve the resolution of any (if multiple) screen(s).

If you need more documentation or samples you simply have to browser [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on NSScreen. The properties names will closely match what MonoMac provides.